# Can anyone ID this set, please?

Tags: set-identification, moc

Has typical City plane tail. Has 2 ADU (Earth Defense) minifigs inside. Cannot find online.
Thank you for your help!

[image: Photo of Plane]

Comment: Welcome! This looks like a MOC, not an official set. A LEGO City airplane tail does not go with Round 2x2 tiles with Star Wars related artwork.

Answer (score 6):

There's a part on the front of the model named [Wedge 10 x 3 Right with White Stripes, Yellow Triangle and Gray Lines Pattern (Stickers) - Set 8093](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50956pb008)

[image]

This piece was available in a single set - [8093-1 Plo Koon's Jedi Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8093-1):

[image]

The model in question is not the same as the set which means it is someone's unique creation (MOC).

Answer (score -1):

I can't make out the "*LEGO*" logo stamp on the studs at the front of the build. Back end top has an asymmetric build flow.  Looks non-official. Fan made.

Comment: The lack of visible LEGO marking on the studs might be explained by the thick layer of grime and the photography artifacts, but the random asymmetry is a rather telling sign, indeed.